# How to live update chart values in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, charts, observablecollection, linechart

I have a LineChart created like this:

```
<Grid.Resources>
                    <local:EngineMeasurementCollection x:Key="EngineMeasurementCollection"/>


                </Grid.Resources>



                    <charting:Chart x:Name="ahorasi" Title="Engine Performance" Margin="-2,0,384,0">
                    <!-- Power curve -->
                    <charting:LineSeries
    Title="Power"
    ItemsSource="{StaticResource EngineMeasurementCollection}"
    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Speed}"
    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Power}" 

    >
                        <!-- Vertical axis for power curve -->
                        <charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                            <charting:LinearAxis
            Orientation="Y"
            Title="Power (hp)"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="250"
            Interval="50"
            ShowGridLines="True"/>
                        </charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                    </charting:LineSeries>
                    <!-- Torque curve -->
                    <charting:LineSeries
    Title="Torque"
    ItemsSource="{StaticResource EngineMeasurementCollection}"
    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Speed}"
    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Torque}">
                        <!-- Vertical axis for torque curve -->
                        <charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                            <charting:LinearAxis
            Orientation="Y"
            Title="Torque (lb-ft)"
            Minimum="50"
            Maximum="300"
            Interval="50"/>
                        </charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                    </charting:LineSeries>
                    <charting:Chart.Axes>
                        <!-- Shared horizontal axis -->
                        <charting:LinearAxis
        Orientation="X"
        Title="Speed (rpm)"
        Interval="1000"
        ShowGridLines="True"/>
                    </charting:Chart.Axes>
                </charting:Chart>
```

Then I have

```
        public class EngineMeasurementCollection : ObservableCollection<EngineMeasurement>
{
    public EngineMeasurementCollection()
    {
        Add(new EngineMeasurement { Speed = 1000, Torque = 100, Power = 20 });
        Add(new EngineMeasurement { Speed = 2000, Torque = 160, Power = 60 });
        Add(new EngineMeasurement { Speed = 3000, Torque = 210, Power = 125 });
        Add(new EngineMeasurement { Speed = 4000, Torque = 220, Power = 160 });
        Add(new EngineMeasurement { Speed = 5000, Torque = 215, Power = 205 });
        Add(new EngineMeasurement { Speed = 6000, Torque = 200, Power = 225 });
        Add(new EngineMeasurement { Speed = 7000, Torque = 170, Power = 200});

    }



}

public class EngineMeasurement
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Torque { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
}`
```

When I run my project the chart works perfect, showing the values created in the constructor, but that's hardcoded, I cant find the way add or remove elements to update the chart.

I don't even understand why the chart shows the provided items at constructor, does a instance of EngineMeasurementCollection is created? automatically? I don't create a new EngineMeasurementCollection.

I tried something like:

```
EngineMeasurement littleitem = new EngineMeasurement();
EngineMeasurementCollection fullitems = new EngineMeasurementCollection();
littleitem.Power = 10;
littleitem.Speed = 1000;
littleitem.Torque = 50;
fullitems.Add(littleitem);
//Up to this point everything works perfect, now I want to update my chart with fullitem values in whatever possible way.
```

I can NOT do ahorasi.ItemsSource = fullitems because .ItemsSource does not exist, I am really confused because, the chart works wonderful when just created, with the hardcoded values, I think update it must be just a single step, but cant find how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your Xaml:-

```
               <local:EngineMeasurementCollection x:Key="EngineMeasurementCollection"/>
```

is creating an instance to the `EngineMeasurementCollection` and its this instance your chart is bound to.

So if you want add new elements to your chart its this instance you need to modify.  Assuming the `Grid` that this is a resource of has the name "LayoutRoot" you can gain access to the collection by adding this property to you `UserControl`:-

```
 public EngineMeasurementCollection CurrentMeasurements
 {
      get { return (EngineMeasurementCollection)LayoutRoot.Resources["EngineMeasurementCollection"]; }
 }
```

Now you add an additional entry with:-

```
CurrentMeasurements.Add(new EngineMeasurement() { Power = 10, Speed = 1000, Torque = 50 } );
```

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony, it looks so easy now, thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My particular problem has been solved, but for futher readers, my UserControl page was a different page than the one I use for the chart, so I added

```
public EngineMeasurementCollection CurrentMeasurements
```

to my chart page, and it works perfect, dont know if theres any implications involved for code it that way.